# Why are my getter/setter not compiling in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, async-await, getter-setter

I have a class with the following getter/setter defined:

```
class ConfigStoreController {
    get debugMode() {
        return (async () => await this.GetConfigParameter("debugMode"))();
        }

    set debugMode(value: string) {
        (async () => await this.SetConfigParameter("debugMode", value))();
    }

    private async GetConfigParameter(parameter: string) {
        return await RX.Storage.getItem(parameter);
    }

    private async SetConfigParameter(param: string, value: string) {
        return await RX.Storage.setItem(param, value);
    }
}

export default new ConfigStoreController();
```

The getter is marked as incorrect because of the setter, that is, if the latter is removed, then the getter is OK.

The error is the following:

> return (async () => await this.GetConfigParameter("debugMode"))();
>   error TS2322: Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'string'.

To be clear, the getter alone compiles fine:

```
get debugMode() {
    return (async () => await this.GetConfigParameter("debugMode"))();
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your getter contains an async operation there is no way to have it directly retrun `string`. It does not matter if you wrap the async operation in an anonymous function, that function call will return a `Promise<string>`. This means the type of the property will be `Promise<string>`

The getter alone works, because the property type would be `Promise<string>` which is not a problem. It stops working if you also have a setter and the parameter of the setter does not have the same type as the return of the `get`.

You can create property that is a `Promise<string>` instead.

```
class ConfigStoreController {
  GetConfigParameter(p: string): Promise<string> {
    return Promise.resolve(p)
  }
  SetConfigParameter(p: string, value: string): Promise<void> {
    return Promise.resolve(void 0)
  }
  get debugMode() {
    return this.GetConfigParameter("debugMode");
  }

  set debugMode(value: Promise<string>) {
    // There is no way to wait for this operation to finish from the outside, this might be an issue
    // Also unhandled errors from the anonymous method are not handled and are not propagated to the caller, since the set is async
    (async () => this.SetConfigParameter("debugMode", await value))(); 
  }
}
```

A better solution is probably to leave the getter and have a `set` method instead:

```
class ConfigStoreController {
  GetConfigParameter(p: string): Promise<string> {
    return Promise.resolve(p)
  }
  SetConfigParameter(p: string, value: string): Promise<void> {
    return Promise.resolve(void 0)
  }
  get debugMode() {
    return this.GetConfigParameter("debugMode");
  }

  async setDebugMode(value: string) {
      this.SetConfigParameter("debugMode", await value)
  }
}
```